# Removing files which are not tracked will be marked as deleted

Tags: git, git-clean

I have the following state in a git repo:

```
git status

On branch whatever
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/whatever' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    docs/file1.docx

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So I will do a:

```
git clean -fdx
```

After that a `git status` will show the following:

```
On branch whatever
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/whatever' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    docs/file1.docx

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I delete files which are not tracked how could it happen that they are marked as deleted?

Comment: With created the file .gitignore

Comment: Or with rm -rf --cache <files>

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. What do you mean by `With created the file .gitignore` ? I have not pattern in `.gitignore` like `*.docx` etc. ? Nor have I created that file at that time...it was not changed...

Comment: I tried replicating, got "nothing to commit" message.

Comment: If the commit was done, the file still exists remotely and therefore you must add it as `git add` and upload.

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. Even if the file were in history, and in the remote, if the last commit doesn't include it there should be no message.

Comment: `git add .` i thinks its the solution

Comment: Are you on a case-insensitive file system, so that the OS cannot create both `docs/file1.docx` *and* `docs/FILE1.docx`? If so, does the current commit have such files in it? If so, you're stuck: your host system can't check out the current commit correctly.

Comment: @torek No I'm Linux.

Comment: Hm, that's quite odd then. "Untracked" means "not in the index, but is in the work-tree" and that's when `git clean` would remove the file, but the second `git status` says that it *is* in the index. I'd need a way to reproduce the problem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this, but I get into the same state sometimes. When it happens, I fix it by running:

```
git clean --force
```

(or `git clean -f`), which removes the untracked files but does *not* cause `git` to mark them as deleted.

For more information, run `git help clean`. It has various other flags and features that you might find helpful.